# what can we use instead of dba_role_privs in postgresql?

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, database-migration

```
  cursor get_roles is
         select substr(granted_role,1,2)||substr(granted_role,4,1)
         from dba_role_privs
         where grantee = p_user_name and
         (granted_role like '%REP' OR
          granted_role like '%MANAGER')
```

Report: Unable to convert system object SYS.DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.
I want to convert the given into Postgresql. please help.

Comment: Most probably [pg_auth_members](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-auth-members.html)

Comment: do you have any document about it?

Comment: You mean other than the manual (the link in my comment)? Then no.

Comment: select value
      into v_original_nls_date_format
      from V$parameter 
      where upper(name) = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
    

Unable to convert system object SYS.V_$PARAMETER?  can you help with this as well please!?

Comment: That's an entirely different question.